# Implementing outside clicks on Lit-Elements

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element, lit-html

I'm making a custom dropdown web component using LitElements and while implementing the click-outside-dropwdown-to-close feature I'm noticing some unexpected behavior that is blocking me. Below in the `async firstUpdated()` function I'm creating the event listener as [recommended in their documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events#add-event-listeners-after-first-paint). Logging out `dropdown` works as expected, but logging out `target` returns the root `<custom-drop-down>...</custom-drop-down>` element every time, which while accurate to an extent, is not specific enough. If there's a better way to handle outside click events I'm all ears.

For reference, here's something that's already built (although the source is hidden) that I'm trying to replicate: https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/dropdown/code/

```
async firstUpdated() {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 0));
  this.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const dropdown = <HTMLElement>this.shadowRoot?.getElementById('dropdown-select');
    const target = <HTMLElement>event.target;
    if (!dropdown?.contains(target)) {
      console.log('im outside');
    }
  });
}    


@customElement('custom-drop-down')
public render(): TemplateResult {
  return html`
    <div>
      <div id="dropdown-select" @action=${this.updateValue}>
        <div class="current-selection" @click=${this.toggleDropdown}>
          ${this.value}
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-options" id="dropdown-options">
          ${this.dropdownItems(this.options)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [click event](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click)'s `target` property is set to the [topmost event target](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#topmost-event-target).

> The topmost event target MUST be the element highest in the rendering order which is capable of being an [event target](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-target).

Because a shadow DOM encapsulates its internal structure, the event is [retargeted to the host element](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events). In your example, the `click` event's `target` is retargeted to the `custom-drop-down` because that is the first and highest element capable of being a target.

If you need to target an element inside your custom element, you can take one of the following approaches:

1. Register an event listener inside your element.
2. Use the [`<slot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) element to fill your custom element with elements that are declared in the light DOM.
3. Use the [`composedPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) on events with [`composed: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed) to determine which internal element your event bubbled from.

---

Here's an example of the functionality I believe you are looking for. If you click on the `Custom Element` it toggles its active state (similar to toggling a dropdown). If you click on any other element on the page, the custom element deactivates itself (similar to hiding a dropdown when it loses focus).

```js
// Define the custom element type
class MySpan extends HTMLSpanElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    
    const text = 'Custom Element.';
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent = `
      span {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .active {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: black;
      }      
    `;
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    this.span.innerText = text;
    this.span.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
      console.log('CUSTOM ELEMENT: Clicked inside custom element.'); 
      this.handleClick(event);
    });
    
    this.shadowRoot.append(style, this.span);
  }
  
  handleClick(event) {
    // If the event is from the internal event listener,
    // the target will be our span element and we can toggle it.
    // If the event is from outside the element, 
    // the target cannot be our span element and we should
    // deactiviate it.
    if (event.target === this.span) {
      this.span.classList.toggle('active');
    }
    else {
      this.span.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
}
customElements.define('my-span', MySpan, { extends: 'span' });

// Insert an instance of the custom element
const div1 = document.querySelector('#target');
const mySpan = new MySpan();
div1.appendChild(mySpan);

// Add an event listener to the page
function handleClick(event) {
  // If we didn't click on the custom element, let it
  // know about the event so it can deactivate its span.
  if (event.target !== mySpan) {
    console.log(`PAGE: Clicked on ${ event.target }. Notifying custom element.`);
    mySpan.handleClick(event);
  }
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => handleClick(event));
```

```css
p {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<p id="target">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a second paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a third paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Okay follow up question... say I was watching for clicks anywhere on the page, not just within the shadow DOM. Would that be possible? I was able to get the composed path bit working, but it only fires when clicking inside the shadow DOM. I added an example to my post that hopefully does a better job of explaining.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. I've added an example of an event listener inside the custom element to handle direct interaction as well as a page-wide event listener to propagate external events into the custom element.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it wasn't an exact match but I was able to piece together a few bits of your input to get a working example.